# What should I replace CCTexture2D initWithImage with?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

What should I replace CCTexture2D initWithImage with?

I have this method:

```
CCTexture2D *noMutableTexture = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]] autorelease];
```

I jumped to definition and found that the only method now is:

```
- (id) initWithData:(const void*)data pixelFormat:(CCTexture2DPixelFormat)pixelFormat pixelsWide:(NSUInteger)width pixelsHigh:(NSUInteger)height contentSize:(CGSize)size
```

and

```
- (id) initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage resolutionType:(ccResolutionType)resolution
```

Im guessing its the latter, but Im not sure how to build the CGImageRef, nor do I know what the ccResolutionType would be.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thx

Comment: what you want? CCSprite or UIImage/CGImage from CCTexture2D ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//! ccResolutionType
typedef enum
{
    //! Unknonw resolution type
    kCCResolutionUnknown,
#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
    //! iPhone resolution type
    kCCResolutioniPhone,
    //! RetinaDisplay resolution type
    kCCResolutioniPhoneRetinaDisplay,
    //! iphone5 resolution type
    kCCResolutioniPhone5Display,
    //! iPad resolution type
    kCCResolutioniPad,
    //! iPad Retina Display resolution type
    kCCResolutioniPadRetinaDisplay,

#elif defined(__CC_PLATFORM_MAC)
    //! Mac resolution type
    kCCResolutionMac,

    //! Mac RetinaDisplay resolution type (???)
    kCCResolutionMacRetinaDisplay,
#endif // platform

} ccResolutionType;
```

Are possible values for resolutionType.

So based on device type, iPhone or iPhone retina (3.5/4 inch) , iPad, iPad retina. The value of resolution type varies.

```
- (id) initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage resolutionType:(ccResolutionType)resolution
```

you can build a CGImageRef like this :

```
UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
CGImageRef someImageRef = someImage.CGImage;
```

you can check your device type like this

```
-(ccResolutionType)resolutionType{
    static NSInteger ret=-1;

    if (ret != -1) return ret;

    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2 )
            ret = kCCResolutioniPadRetinaDisplay;
        else
            ret = kCCResolutioniPad;
    }
    else
    {
        if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2 ){
            BOOL isWideScreenEnabled = (BOOL)(fabs((double)[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -
                                                   (double)568) < DBL_EPSILON);

            if (isWideScreenEnabled) {
                ret = kCCResolutioniPhone5Display;
            }
            else ret = kCCResolutioniPhoneRetinaDisplay;
        }
        else
            ret = kCCResolutioniPhone;
    }

       if(ret == -1)
        ret = kCCResolutionUnknown;


    return ret;
}
```

So,overall if you want to create a CCTexture from UIImage then

```
UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
CGImageRef someImageRef = someImage.CGImage;
CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithCGImage:someImageRef resolutionType:kCCResolutionUnknown ];
```

or

```
CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithCGImage:someImageRef resolutionType:[self resolutionType]];
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add a texture to the texture cache, the method returns you the texture. From the docs of CCTextureCache :

```
-(CCTexture2D*) addImage: (NSString*) fileimage:
```

so in your case :

```
CCTexture2D *noMutableTexture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"myImage.png"];
```

Comment: Both `front = [CCTexture2D addImage:@"iphone4_front.jpg"];
` & `front = [[CCTexture2D sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"iphone4_front.jpg"];
` return a "class method not found, return type defaults to id".

Comment: CCTextureCache not CCTexture2D. Another way to get a texture is to create a CCSprite and use the 'texture' property of the sprite.